# Can't run js file

Tags: javascript, html

i was trying to create a blackjack game using html and jscript and this is what happened i load de js file in the html and i know it's loaded beacause debugger tell's me de file has been encoutered but the file is not running.
new to js

here are the files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>BlackJack by RuiVieira</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="zonaBanca">
    <h1>Banca</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="zonaJogoBanca">
  </div>
  <div id="zonaJogador">    
    <h1>Jogador</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="zonaJogoJogador">    
  </div>
  <div id="zonaAposta">
    <h2>Aposta</h2>
    <button id="subir">+1</button>
    <button id="parar">stop</button>
    <div>
        <input id="valorAposta" type="number" min="0" step="1"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="botaoAposta">Apostar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="blackj.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript file:

```
alert('xupasaoquadrado');
var baralho =    ['Ao','2o','3o','4o','5o','6o','7o','8o','9o','10o','Vo','Do','Ko', 'Ae','2e','3e','4e','5e','6e','7e','8e','9e','10e','Ve','De','Ke',
        'Ap','2p','3p','4p','5p','6p','7p','8p','9p','10p','Vp','Dp','Kp', 'Ac','2c','3c','4c','5c','6c','7c','8c','9c','10c','Vc','Dc','Kc'];
var botaoAposta = document.getElementById('botaoAposta');
var valorAposta;
botaoAposta.onclick = function() {
alert('xupas');
valorAposta = document.getElementById('valorAposta').value;
alert('xupas1');
if(valorAposta = document.getElementById('valorAposta').value != null){

}
else{
    alert('iserir valor de aposta (números inteiros)');
}
}
```

Comment: So the alert from the first line doesn't occur? But no errors in the browser's dev console?

Comment: your code isn't wrapped in a `document.load`-event. So your code is compiled when the page opens, but not when the document is done loading. Therefor the id's of the elements you use are not created yet, so the code won't work.

Comment: Do you include google chrome console results when load the page, maybe there are an error, possible with .onclick that it's not defined because the element is not ready yet

Comment: @Jorrex His `<script>` tag is at the end of the body, so all the elements have been loaded.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, at least the part posted here is working properly (tried it locally with Firefox). So either there is more code to this or something else (sth. network-related) is breaking it, even though you said debugger is "encountering" it. Fact is, there is no extra argument missing to make this code run instead of just being loaded. `<script>` is loading and running the mentioned script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s04zx776/) I see the error, instead bind the event with onclick use addEventListener to add handler to event when the object is ready.

```
   alert('xupasaoquadrado');
    var baralho = ['Ao','2o','3o','4o','5o','6o','7o','8o','9o','10o','Vo','Do','Ko', 'Ae','2e','3e','4e','5e','6e','7e','8e','9e','10e','Ve','De','Ke','Ap','2p','3p','4p','5p','6p','7p','8p','9p','10p','Vp','Dp','Kp', 'Ac','2c','3c','4c','5c','6c','7c','8c','9c','10c','Vc','Dc','Kc'];
    var botaoAposta = document.getElementById('botaoAposta');
    var valorAposta; 
    botaoAposta.addEventListener("click",function(e){
   alert('xupas');
        valorAposta = document.getElementById('valorAposta').value;
        alert('xupas1');

        if(valorAposta = document.getElementById('valorAposta').value != null){

        }
        else{
            alert('iserir valor de aposta (números inteiros)');
        }
},false);
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your javascript code in a `load` event handler

```
window.addEventListener("load", loaded, false);

function loaded() {
  alert('xupasaoquadrado');
  var baralho = ['Ao', '2o', '3o', '4o', '5o', '6o', '7o', '8o', '9o', '10o', 'Vo', 'Do', 'Ko', 'Ae', '2e', '3e', '4e', '5e', '6e', '7e', '8e', '9e', '10e', 'Ve', 'De', 'Ke', 'Ap', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p', '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', 'Vp', 'Dp', 'Kp', 'Ac', '2c', '3c', '4c', '5c', '6c', '7c', '8c', '9c', '10c', 'Vc', 'Dc', 'Kc'];
  var botaoAposta = document.getElementById('botaoAposta');
  var valorAposta;
  botaoAposta.onclick = function() {
    alert('xupas');
    valorAposta = document.getElementById('valorAposta').value;
    alert('xupas1');
    if (valorAposta = document.getElementById('valorAposta').value != null) {

    } else {
      alert('iserir valor de aposta (números inteiros)');
    }
  }
}
```

This way, when the page is opened, it'll execute the code the moment the page has loaded (meaning the DOM has been created and all the elements are on the page).

Then, when the javascript code runs, it'll encounter all the `document.getElementById()` statements and find the corresponding element in the DOM.

Comment: As mentioned in similar post before the script is included at end of HTML file and thus it is pretty capable of accessing all the elements defined in there. Sticking with `load` event of window is even worse than sticking with `DOMContentLoaded` event of document as the former is emitted long after the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Include your code in **[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)** event, this event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    alert('xupasaoquadrado');
    var baralho = ['Ao','2o','3o','4o','5o','6o','7o','8o','9o','10o','Vo','Do','Ko', 'Ae','2e','3e','4e','5e','6e','7e','8e','9e','10e','Ve','De','Ke','Ap','2p','3p','4p','5p','6p','7p','8p','9p','10p','Vp','Dp','Kp', 'Ac','2c','3c','4c','5c','6c','7c','8c','9c','10c','Vc','Dc','Kc'];
    var botaoAposta = document.getElementById('botaoAposta');
    var valorAposta; 
    var botaoAposta.onclick = function() {
        alert('xupas');
        valorAposta = document.getElementById('valorAposta').value;
        alert('xupas1');

        if(valorAposta = document.getElementById('valorAposta').value != null){

        }
        else{
            alert('iserir valor de aposta (números inteiros)');
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: The `<script>` tag is at the end of the body, so all the HTML has been parsed and loaded.